# Resetting a DropDownList to its initial option after pop-up closes JQM

Tags: jquery-mobile, popup

I'm having a DDL inside a popup but whenever I close the popup and reopen it, it keeps its last selected option. What I'm trying to do is to call the popupafterclose event and set the DDL to its initial option, but it does not seem to work..

```
$("#popup").on("popupafterclose", function (event) {
            $('#ddl1').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

The initial option of the DDL is a disabled hidden selected option.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to **[refresh the selectmenu widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh)** as well:

```
$("#popup").on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
    $('#ddl1').find('option:first').prop('selected', 'selected');
    $('#ddl1').selectmenu("refresh", true);
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/rLErqN)**

Comment: Thanks it works! What if I have more than 1 DDL inside the popup, will this also work with more than 1 ?

Comment: @Jadenkun, sure, just give all the selects the same class and use it as selector. See updated CodePen:  http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/rLErqN  (please consider marking answers as accepted when they solve your issue. That way future searchers know the issue was resolved and can find answers more easily)